# What is the HTML unicode character for a "tall" right chevron?

Tags: html, css, unicode, fonts

I am looking for a unicode right chevron character, with no handle on the left, and I would like the top point and bottom point to be spread far apart. Similar to Ubuntu's (website) arrow in the search box.

I don't want `&raquo;`(») or `&rarr;`(→) or simply `>`.  The problem with the first is there are two chevrons, not just one.  The other one is way too small and has a handle. The third one has a vertex that is too acute.

I have looked at just about every unicode chart there is, and if there is none, then I'll just have to use an image (like Ubuntu).  I'll deal with it, but that is a last resort.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You could draw it with svg...or canvas..

Comment: I wonder if it is possible with CSS? http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Comment: @ScottSimpson Dear me, +1 for a really good reference. @ Ohgodwhy As far as svg or canvas, I could try that.

Comment: The question is closed, so I can't post an answer. Anyway, here is what I suggest, use the character `>` and then add css like `transform: scaleX(.5)' to stretch and squish the character. http://codepen.io/cruznunez/pen/rLoQNX

Comment: The 4 single chevron right-like characters in the Unicode are:
• > 003E greater-than sign
• › 203A single right-pointing angle quotation mark
• 〉232A right-pointing angle bracket
• 〉 3009 right angle bracket
I personally find that none suite my needs, I typically go for Font Awesome angle-right.

Comment: **Unicode.org**: https://unicode.org/charts/nameslist/n_2700.html

Comment: wht about › Alt-0155 (Windows) ?

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Use '›'

`&rsaquo;` -> single right angle quote. For single left angle quote, use `&lsaquo;`

Comment: Thank you! That is what i was looking for. However, I don't know if it's because of the font I am using (Open Sans?), using `&rsaquo;` doesn't work, so I used it's equivalent which was listed `&#8250;` (<< Just for future readers!)

Comment: @ModernDesigner Yeah, Open Sans is Unicode, AFAIK, and the &rsaquo; is an ASCII entity, so that makes sense. Glad you figured it out. Also, for what its worth, check out http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/

Comment: Or how about `&#x3009;`? Found on http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/cjk_symbols_and_punctuation.html.

Comment: It is a quotation mark, not an arrow of any kind, and it can hardly be called “tall”.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela That's what font-size is for. It's what Twitter Bootstrap uses for the next button on their carousel, so it works just fine if we're not trying to attach any meaning to it other than "the pointy end indicates the direction."

Comment: @TiesonT., “tall” as an attribute of a character can hardly mean anything but the relative size of the glyph in a font. Otherwise, you could call any character “tall” just because you can set the font size to 100pt.

Comment: HTML is in unicode these days - there's no need to use entities for most  characters.

Comment: there's also `&rang;`. Here's a [great resource for HTML entities](http://entity-lookup.leftlogic.com/).

Answer (score 31):

From the description and from the reference to the search box in the [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/) site, I gather that you actually want an *arrowhead* character pointing to the right. There are no Unicode characters designed to be used as arrowheads, but some of them may visually resemble an arrowhead.

In particular, if you draw your idea of the character at [Shapecatcher.com](http://shapecatcher.com/), you will find many suggestions, such as “〉” RIGHT-POINTING ANGLE BRACKET' (U+232A) and “❭” MEDIUM RIGHT-POINTING ANGLE BRACKET ORNAMENT (U+276D).

Such characters generally have limited support in fonts, so you would need to carefully write a longish `font-family` list or to use a downloadable font. See my [Guide to using special characters in HTML](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/characters.html).

Especially if the intended use is as a symbol in a search box, as the reference to the Ubuntu page suggests, it is questionable whether you should use a character at all. It’s not really an element of text here; rather, a graphic symbol that accompanies text but isn’t a part of it. So why take all the trouble with using a character (safely), when it isn’t really a character?

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I _really_ do _not_ care whether or not it's actually called an arrowhead. Quotation mark or not, it's an arrow. And it's tall. And it works in my font. And I'd rather use a character than an image because it's easier. Thank you for your interest in my question though! :D

Comment: @ModernDesigner, then, next time, take more time to formulate your question; here you had written: “I am looking for a unicode right arrow character”, without specifying the intended use.

Comment: Sorry, thought it was obvious enough...

Comment: +1 for caveat re font support.

Comment: And the corresponding one: left-pointing angle bracket (warning, code point over nine thousand): http://shapecatcher.com/unicode/info/9001

Comment: wow, didn't know about it, so +1 for shapecatcher!!!

Comment: To me, this should be the right answer. This is a "tall" chevron. In most typefaces I know, the &rsaquo; is very small, smaller than letters.

Answer (score 13):

I use ▸ (0x25B8) for the right arrow, often to show a collapsed list; and I pair it with ▾ (0x25BE) to show the list opened up. Both are unobtrusive.

Comment: [▸](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+25B8) `Black Right-Pointing Small Triangle` and [▾](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+25BE) `Black Down-Pointing Small Triangle`